# Why is it not possible to place DIVs anywhere with Gridster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridster

I'm a little bit depressed because I need a customizable grid (moving and resizing DIVs) like Gridster, you can check the demo here: http://gridster.net/

Basically I need all the features Gridster is offering, like dragging and dropping DIVs, resizing them and saving the positions of the DIVs and loading them.
However, there is one problem. It is not possible to drop the DIVs anywhere.
In the Screenshot I want to drop the red highlighted DIV on that place, but it will snap to the upper highlighted area.

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150307/z2qlxelp.png

Is there any solution to fix this problem?
Also, could someone explain me how the Grid of Gridster works? Is there a "virtual grid" behind that or how is it realised?

If someone has a solution for that problem, an example would be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if gridster supports this but you can try [gridstack.js](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) with options [`{float: true}`](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#options). I've started gridstack.js because I need responsive layout support. But now it has bunch of features which gridster doesn't have (like knockout.js support, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The original Gridster.js project is abandoned. However, there is a well maintained fork that provides the functionality you need:

https://github.com/dsmorse/gridster.js

Take a look at the [sticky-position](https://github.com/dsmorse/gridster.js/blob/master/demos/sticky-postion.html%20stick-position) code for an example.

Also, take a look at Angular Gridster:

https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster